# Snow appears in the back of my divs

Tags: html

I've exactly this website but the problem is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPQ9N.png

As you can see, the snow doesn't appear infront of the image (there is a div there), also it doesn't appear in front of the box.

I used these codes:

```
<script src="http://www.ristoranteaibarchi.com/snowjs/snowstorm.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.ristoranteaibarchi.com/snowjs/snowstorm-min.js"></script>
```

However it worked on: http://www.ristoranteaibarchi.com/ but doesn't work on mine which I don't know why :/

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We tend to not like external links, because they become stale, and we want S/O to be forever. So please edit your question and put everything in there (including all the relevant code). If you can't describe the problem in words, you can insert an image.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try and explain a bit more in order to receive a proper answer.

Anyway ... im gonna put my .02 cents here.

Since you specified that the snow shows on the back of the other divs this might mean that this might be an z-index issue.

Thats all i can tell only from what you told.

So:

1) give us some more info.
2) try and change the z-index of the div that contains the snow and the z-index of the content (for example purposes im gonna supose that the other's div name is content).

```
.snow { z-index: 1000; }
.content { z-index: 999; }
```